# Заяц в консоли есть, а без консоли его нет!

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

День || Вечер || Ночь вам приятнейшие!

Пишу я тут мега-супер парсер, с крайне простым функционалом - брать карточки товара, сдирать фотографию, название и цену, и вставлять эти воистинну заурядные данные в табличку.
Всё шло в целом нормально - под Scorpions - Wind Of Change пальцы стучали по клавишам, вдалеке раздавались визжащие от радости дети, маниакально преследующие друг-друга на льду. КАК ВДРУГ!

Командная строка NodeJS, при очередном запуске для проверки моей криворукости, начала выдавать непонятную ошибку:

```
E:\portfolio\multi-parser\multi-parser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221
            throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
                  ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:90
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (E:\portfolio\multi-parser\multi-parser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (E:\portfolio\multi-parser\multi-parser\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async Test.Scanning__Product__Cards (E:\portfolio\multi-parser\multi-parser\parser.js:202:33)
```

На указанной строке находиться следующий код:

```
async Scanning__Product__Cards ( object_index ) {

            for ( let link_object of this.storage.objects[ object_index ].directory_links ) {

                for ( let key in link_object ) {

                    for ( let link of link_object[ key ] ) {


                        const current_page = await this.browser.newPage( );
                        await current_page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout( 0 );
                        await current_page.goto( link );
                        

                        const INDACATION_FLAG       = this.storage.objects[ object_index ].product_flags.indacation_flag;
                        const FLAG_PRODUCT_PHOTOS   = this.storage.objects[ object_index ].product_flags.flag_product_photos;
                        const NAME_FLAG             = this.storage.objects[ object_index ].product_flags.name_flag;
                        const ADDRESS_FLAG          = this.storage.objects[ object_index ].product_flags.address_flag;
                        const BASIC_PRICE_FLAG      = this.storage.objects[ object_index ].product_flags.basic_price_flag;
                        const TIME_PRICE_FLAG       = this.storage.objects[ object_index ].product_flags.time_price_flag;


                        const number_of_products = await current_page.evaluate(({ INDACATION_FLAG }) => {

                            return document.querySelectorAll( INDACATION_FLAG ).length;

                        }, { INDACATION_FLAG });
                        

                        for ( let element = 0; element <= 2; element++ ) {

                            const photo_extraction      = await current_page.evaluate(({ INDACATION_FLAG, FLAG_PRODUCT_PHOTOS, element }) => {

                                return document.querySelectorAll( `${ INDACATION_FLAG } ${ FLAG_PRODUCT_PHOTOS }` )[ element ].src;

                            }, { INDACATION_FLAG, FLAG_PRODUCT_PHOTOS, element });

                            const name_extraction       = await current_page.evaluate(({ INDACATION_FLAG, NAME_FLAG, element }) => {    !!! Вот тут строка на которой происходит ошибка    !!!

                                return document.querySelectorAll( `${ INDACATION_FLAG } ${ NAME_FLAG }` )[ element ].textContent;

                            }, { INDACATION_FLAG, NAME_FLAG, element });

                            this.storage.objects[ object_index ].product_data.push({
                                // product_address  : product_address,
                                photo_extraction    : photo_extraction,
                                name_extraction     : name_extraction,
                                // price_extraction     : price_extraction,
                                // temporary_price  : temporary_price
                            });

                        }


                    }

                }

            }

    }
```

Что же, внутренне смирившись, я начал искать причину сие программного недовольства. И... не нашёл.

В консоли браузера всё нормально определяется, также поток программы спокойно находит все пути до изображений, но текст нивкакую находить не хочет.

Сканирую с этой страницы - https://www.ubuy.co.at/en/category/cell-phones-accessories/accessories/powerbanks-7073960011

Путник IT-рая, если ты сможешь мне помочь, я буду безмерно благодарен, а если ещё и вставишь пару строк о качестве моего низкопробного кода, буду просто сиять от радости!

Заранее благодарю за внимание!

Comment: очевидно таких элементов на странице не найдено. причем может быть куча. сначала удостоверься в этом, проверив что вернет `document.querySelectorAll`, так же проверь, какой текст страницы тебе вообще пришел.